# Is there a smarter way for getting the indices of a list sliced with a sliced object?

Tags: python, list, indexing, range, slice

I have a list A of unknown length and a slice object that indicates important elements in this list. How can I get the according indices as a list B? (So Instead of e.g. `slice(0, 5, 1)` I get `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`) This should work even if I don't know the length of the list before defining the slice object and also for slices like `s=slice(None, None, 20)`.

My solution is the following:

```
indices_B = list(range(len(my_list_A)))[my_slice]
```

It works, but I have a feeling that there has to be a smarter way that is also easier to understand. (Using `range(len(somelist))` feels definitely wrong)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
indices_B = range(*my_slice.indices(len(my_list_A)))
```

https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#slice.indices

Comment: I think you have to convert to list each range

Comment: Rarely: ranges support most list operations (they're proper sequences) and they're much, much cheaper. If you need to pass that to something which only works with actual lists then yes, but that's a separate concern.

Comment: the OP question indicates that the desired output is a list

Comment: your code will not work for my_slice=slice(None, None, 20)

Comment: "the OP question indicates that the desired output is a list" the OP wants the indices, they never actually say that they *need* a list

Comment: "your code will not work for my_slice=slice(None, None, 20)" true. The one from the stdlib will work though. I'll just remove the "simple version" since it apparently detracts from the solution.

Comment: Thank you, indeed I was initially thinking about proceeding with a list of indices but do not actually need one. Your solution works perfectly fine for my usecase.